# How to replace hyphens with underscores within html tags using preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I am trying to replace hyphens with underscores ONLY within the `div` and `input` ids. Below is what I tried without success. My code replaces hyphens but does it at wrong places.

It should only replace the hyphens within the strings such as `id="input-field-1"`, `id="input-field-1"`, etc. All hyphens in outer classes should remain as is.

```
$string =
'<div class="block-wrapper">'.
    '<div class="block">'.
        '<div id="bl-inner-id-1" class="block-inner"></div>'.
            '<input id="input-field-1" class="input" type="radio">'.
    '</div>'.
    '<div class="block">'.
        '<div id="bl-inner-id-2" class="block-inner"></div>'.
            '<input id="input-field-2" class="input" type="radio">'.
    '</div>'.
'</div>';

$search1 = "/[^\<div id\=\"](-)[^class\=\"block\">]/";
$search2 = "/[^\<input id\=\"](-)[^type\=\"radio\">]/";
$replace = "_";

echo preg_replace($search1, $replace, $string);

echo preg_replace($search2, $replace, $string);
```

I just want to know how to do this with `preg_replace`. `preg_replace_callback` may not suit in my particular case.

Comment: I suggest experimenting with DOM tree parsers for this sort of thing. In the case of <div>a<divb><div>c</div>d</div>e</div>f</div> your regex will only pickup a,b,c,d and leave off e and f.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree that DOM parsers such as Javascript are much better suited for this type of task, as mentioned by Dimi in the question comments. That being said, I can understand why there might be a need to use PHP for this, such as the constraints of a specific project.

Using only [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) could lead to issues though, as we don't always know where the id text will be within a `<div>` or `<input>` tag (unless the HTML string is always formatted in a very specific way). Because of this, performing a regex match to find id attributes only within div/input tags would most likely require [variable length lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which are not supported in most regex implementations.

Instead of replacing all the hypens using a single regex, you might try breaking the string up into separate components and then replace the block of text for each id. I have added a working PHP example of this this below, with explainations of each step in the PHP comments:

```
$string =
'<div class="block-wrapper">'.
    '<div class="block">'.
        '<div id="bl-inner-id-1" class="block-inner"></div>'.
            '<input id="input-field-1" class="input" type="radio">'.
    '</div>'.
    '<div class="block">'.
        '<div id="bl-inner-id-2" class="block-inner"></div>'.
            '<input id="input-field-2" class="input" type="radio">'.
    '</div>'.
'</div>';

// Find <div> and <input> start tags in the string and store their contents in an array
preg_match_all('/<(div|input)[^>]+>/', $string, $div_input);

// Loop through the array of <div> and <input> tags
foreach ($div_input[0] as $old_tag) {
    // Array element [0] was selected here because preg_match_all also returns
    // the parenthesized subpattern results as $div_input[1], $div_input[2], etc

    // Find id attributes containing a hyphen in the current HTML tag
    preg_match('/ id="[^"]*-[^"]*"/', $old_tag, $id_text);

    // Only proceed if a match was found
    if (!empty($id_text[0])) {

        // Create a new string for the current tag and replace the hypens in the id text
        $new_tag = str_replace($id_text[0], str_replace('-', '_', $id_text[0]), $old_tag);

        // Replace the current tag with the new corrected one in the main HTML string
        $string = str_replace($old_tag, $new_tag, $string);
    }
}

echo $string;
```